# What is the difference between setting a default value of a class property inside or outside of the constructor?

Tags: angularjs, typescript

My code looks like this:

```
interface IConfigService {

    admin: {
        x: number;
    }

class ConfigService implements IConfigService {

    admin = this.getDefaultAdminConfigs();

    constructor() {
        this.admin = this.getDefaultAdminConfigs();
    }

private getDefaultAdminConfigs = () => {
        return {
            x: 99
        };
    }
}
```

Can someone tell me is there any difference between setting the value of admin outside or inside the constructor when I am using AngularJS to set up my configService?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not in your case. It is simply a matter of *what gets executed last*. The constructor body is executed *after* the inline initialization e.g.  :

```
class Foo {
    admin = 123;
    constructor() {
        this.admin = 456;
    }
}

var foo = new Foo();
console.log(foo.admin); // 456
```

It might more relevant when you have an XHR in the constructor or some other property you want to init before this one.

Note: Inline initialization is also executed in order of definition.